# JSON can't contain the entire List<String>

Tags: android, json, string, list, jackson

I am creating an app which sends a list of String to a remote server. 
I am using the Jackson library in order to create the JSONs.
The problem is that I can't put a List with more than 250 strings in the JSON. 
The JSON is created but not "closed". Here is what I mean:

```
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        mapper.writeValue(out, myStringList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, new String(out.toString()));
```

And this is the result:

```
  ["s1","s2",....,"s249",
```

And the JSON is left as it is.

Is there any limitation on the size of the JSON that can be built?

Thanks

Comment: LogCat truncates its output. Do not use LogCat for logging long strings. Instead, log the output of `out.toString().endsWith("]")` to see if it is being closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! :-D